# magento custom admin module save action not working

Tags: magento

All I have created magento 1.8 custom module for admin.
It has grid and the add item option. In database table it has 2 fields ID [Auto increment] and NAME.
Everything working fine but when I click on save button it shows the success message but the name field data not saving to the database. only ID is incrementing and shown in the grid

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fondation_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Item information')));
    $fieldset->addField('Name', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Name'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'title',
    ));
    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFondationData()) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFondationData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFondationData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('fondation_data')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('fondation_data')->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

my **saveAction** function

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getModel('fondation/fondation');
        $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: See how the `$data` variable looks before calling `$model->setData($data)`. If it has as keys all the fields in your table (except primary key) then try clearing the cache. Even if the cache is disabled the table schema cache is still kept by ZF.

Comment: var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost()),check form post data is working or not

Comment: It says Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /var/www/html/magento_store/app/code/local/Npm/Fondation/controllers/Adminhtml/FondationController.php, line 61 when I add your line

Comment: @user2277313: change the database field NAME to title or change $fieldset->addField('Name' to $fieldset->addField('title' and then click on the submit button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct. if you have the field name "**Name**" in database table then use this code

```
 $fieldset->addField('Name', 'text', array(
  'label'     => Mage::helper('fondation')->__('Name'),
  'class'     => 'required-entry',
  'required'  => true,
  'name'      => 'Name',
));
```

Comment: Hello Same Issue with me. it will display array but not save in database. what you change to add new field in extestion

Comment: Check your field name in database field and in your addField function ... both must be same

Comment: yes both are same. but any code create in index.controller for adding new field. i am custmize in one module.

Comment: Now it creates the directory but files is not put into that directory